# How to remove the default page on one.com?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a one.com account and I uploaded my website to my webspace but my website isn't showing up, instead I see the default one.com welcome page saying "XY.com is hosted by one.com"

I've been digging around the admin dashboard and one.com docs but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up an FTP connecting (or SSH connection) to your domain to remove the webpage they deployed by hand and then upload your own website

Comment: Yes, I cleaned out my root directory. It's still showing up.

Comment: And also uploaded the new website?

Comment: as you can read here: https://www.one.com/en/product/ftp You need to be sure you add an idex.html file